# How to pass arguments to reconectingclientfactory

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn

I have some problems to passing argument to reconectingclientfactory:

```
class MyClientFactory(WebSocketClientFactory, ReconnectingClientFactory):

protocol = MyClientProtocol
maxDelay=90
maxRetries=10000

def __init__(ver,cfg,*args,**kwargs):
    self.sysVer=ver
    self.sysCfg=cfg 
    super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)



def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
    print("Client connection failed {0} to: {1} .. retrying ..".format(reason,connector))
    self.retry(connector)

def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
    print("Client connection lost {0} to {1} .. retrying ..".format(reason,connector))
    self.retry(connector)
```

and when i calling:

```
factory = MyClientFactory('ws:/mywswebserver/websocket/', ver=sys_ver, cfg=sys_cfg,protocols={"wsprotocol"})
```

there is a error like:

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'cfg'
```

Can anybody tell me what i'm dooing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use or non-use of `super` is part of the (generally undocumented) public interface of a method.  Also, `super` doesn't really allow for the signature of a method to be changed anywhere in the hierarchy.  Effectively, it is not a useful tool for passing custom configuration to a specific class in the hierarchy.

That said:

```
class MyClientFactory(WebSocketClientFactory, ReconnectingClientFactory):
    def __init__(ver,cfg,*args,**kwargs):
```

You forgot `self` in this signature.  Therefore in:

```
factory = MyClientFactory('ws:/mywswebserver/websocket/', ver=sys_ver, cfg=sys_cfg,protocols={"wsprotocol"})
```

You are passing `'ws:/mywswebserver/websocket/'` as the `cfg` argument.  Then you are also passing `sys_cfg` as another value.  Thus, you have an exception about passing multiple values for `cfg`.

Your immediately exception will be fixed by adding `self` to the signature of your `__init__`.  However, you will probably then encounter further problems.

Comment: yes, i made mistake, but even i add a self instance, nothing has changed..still i have TypeError...

Comment: As I said ... further problems.  It's not possible to fix all of them here because your example isn't self-contained or minimal and I don't know what behavior you expect.  I explained why you get this specific type error.  If you want to know more, you should probably open a new question (consider reading http://sscce.org/ first)

Comment: I found the way... . I use a partial(), and every thing goes well. So I think it will be OK.